# Convert String back to List

Tags: python, string, csv

I messed up yesterday and saved a datframe to csv and in that dataframe I had a column which was a list of strings.  Now that list of strings, is a string(of a list of strings) when I import it back into python from a csv.  Is there a way I can, upon importing, change it back to a list of strings?

Example:

```
testList = localGov["DataElements"][4]

testList
Out[62]: "['Ethnicity', 'Sex', 'Cause of Death', 'Count', 'Percent']"
```

The closest I have been able to come is using the following but it leaves a whitespace in front of some of the characters.

```
testList.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(",")
Out[74]: ['Ethnicity', ' Sex', ' Cause of Death', ' Count', ' Percent']
```

Comment: Building on your work, you can do `[x.lstrip() for x in testList.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(",")]`

Comment: Another nice way to solve it is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split-python/43067525

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) is for :

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> 
>>> literal_eval( "['Ethnicity', 'Sex', 'Cause of Death', 'Count', 'Percent']")
['Ethnicity', 'Sex', 'Cause of Death', 'Count', 'Percent']
```

Comment: was going to answer the same way

Comment: @VigneshKalai then you obviously think this is a good answer. But no upvote?