# Split by comma and how to exclude comma from quotes in split

Tags: python, split

python 2.7 code

```
cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"' 
newStr = cStr.split(',')
print newStr  # -> ['"aaaa"','"bbbb"','"ccc','ddd"' ]
```

but, I want this result.

```
result = ['"aaa"','"bbb"','"ccc,ddd"']
```

Comment: why not split on " and then delete all result that has a size of 1 ?

Comment: Can you not split using '\",\"' ? and then if you still want the quotation marks add them in afterwards.

Answer (score 33):

The solution using [***re.split()***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function:

```
import re

cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"'
newStr = re.split(r',(?=")', cStr)

print newStr
```

The output:

```
['"aaaa"', '"bbbb"', '"ccc,ddd"']
```

---

`,(?=")` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that delimiter `,` is followed by double quote `"`

Comment: How to split () when cha (10) is followed by "aaa"?

Comment: @JongpyoJeon, what do mean with *" Next chr(10) split ?*

Comment: alist = '"aaa","bbb","ccc,ddd" chr(10) "a-1","b-1","c-1"'
There is chr (10) between "ccc,ddd" and "a-1" 

I want...

result = [ ["aaa","bbb","ccc,ddd"],["a-1","b-1","c-1.....chr(10)xxx "] ]

Answer (score 25):

Try to use CSV.

```
import csv
cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"'
newStr = [ '"{}"'.format(x) for x in list(csv.reader([cStr], delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[0] ]

print newStr
```

Check [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Comment: I'd recommend doing "next(csv.reader([cStr]))" instead of "list(csv.reader([cStr]))[0]".

Answer (score 18):

By using regex try this:

```
COMMA_MATCHER = re.compile(r",(?=(?:[^\"']*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])*[^\"']*$)")
split_result = COMMA_MATCHER.split(string)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

pyparsing has a builtin expression, `commaSeparatedList`:

```
cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"' 
import pyparsing as pp
print(pp.commaSeparatedList.parseString(cStr).asList())
```

prints:

```
['"aaaa"', '"bbbb"', '"ccc,ddd"']
```

You can also add a parse-time action to strip those double-quotes (since you probably just want the content, not the quotation marks too):

```
csv_line = pp.commaSeparatedList.copy().addParseAction(pp.tokenMap(lambda s: s.strip('"')))
print(csv_line.parseString(cStr).asList())
```

gives:

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc,ddd']
```

Comment: For anyone reading this a few years later, `commaSeparatedList` has been deprecated in favour of `common.comma_separated_list`

Answer (score 4):

I liked [Mark de Haan'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594403/4833314) solution but I had to rework it, as it removed the quote characters (although they were needed) and therefore an assertion in his example failed. I also added two additional parameters to deal with different separators and quote characters.

```
def tokenize( string, separator = ',', quote = '"' ):
    """
    Split a comma separated string into a List of strings.

    Separator characters inside the quotes are ignored.

    :param string: A string to be split into chunks
    :param separator: A separator character
    :param quote: A character to define beginning and end of the quoted string
    :return: A list of strings, one element for every chunk
    """
    comma_separated_list = []

    chunk = ''
    in_quotes = False

    for character in string:
        if character == separator and not in_quotes:
            comma_separated_list.append(chunk)
            chunk = ''

        else:
            chunk += character
            if character == quote:
                in_quotes = False if in_quotes else True

    comma_separated_list.append( chunk )

    return comma_separated_list
```

And the tests...

```
def test_tokenizer():
    string = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"' 

    expected = ['"aaaa"', '"bbbb"', '"ccc,ddd"']
    actual = tokenize(string)

    assert expected == actual
```

Comment: This is the best solution (and it worked for me), no lib used, all the code is right there to have finer control as we want.

Comment: worked for Stable Diffusion's parameter extraction on something line this: 
 `(...), ControlNet 0 Control Mode: Balanced, ControlNet 0 Preprocessor Parameters: "(512, 64, 64)"'`

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to use regex in this case.
`re.findall('".*?"', cStr)` returns exactly what you need

asterisk is greedy wildcard, if you used `'".*"'`, it would return maximal match, i.e. everything in between the very first and the very last double quote. The question mark makes it non greedy, so `'".*?"'` returns the smallest possible match.

Answer (score 2):

It is always better to use existing libraries when you can, but I was struggling to get my specific use case to work with all the above answers, so I wrote my own for python 3.9 (will probably work until 3.6, and removing the type hinting will get you to 2.x compatability).

```py
def separate(string) -> List[str]:
    """
    Split a comma separated string into a List of strings.

    Resulting list elements are trimmed of double quotes.
    Comma's inside double quotes are ignored.

    :param string: A string to be split into chunks
    :return: A list of strings, one element for every chunk
    """
    comma_separated_list: List[str] = []

    chunk: str = ''
    in_quotes: bool = False

    for character in string:
        if character == ',' and not in_quotes:
            comma_separated_list.append(chunk)
            chunk = ''

        elif character == '"':
            in_quotes = False if in_quotes else True

        else:
            chunk += character

    comma_separated_list.append(chunk)
    return comma_separated_list
```

And the tests...

```py
def test_separator():
    string = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"' 

    expected = ['"aaaa"', '"bbbb"', '"ccc,ddd"']
    actual = separate(string)

    assert expected == actual
```

Comment: the assertion fails because in the actual result the quotes are absent, whereas in expected array - not

Answer (score 1):

You can first split the string by `"` then filter out `''` or `','`, finally format it, it may be the simplest way:

```
['"%s"' % s for s in cStr.split('"') if s and s != ',']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: if you use split, you can split by a string, not a single char: `cStr[1:-1].split('","')`

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser. You can build your own, or you may be able to press one of the library ones into service. In this case, `json` could be (ab)used.

```
import json

cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"' 
jstr = '[' + cStr + ']'
result = json.loads( jstr)             # ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc,ddd']
result = [ '"'+r+'"' for r in result ] # ['"aaaa"', '"bbbb"', '"ccc,ddd"']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard module, you have to install it via pip, but as an option try tssplit:

```
In [3]: from tssplit import tssplit
In [4]: tssplit('"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"', quote='"', delimiter=',')                                                            
Out[4]: ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc,ddd']
```