# Python for a list of strings, if a string contains a character, concatenate it with the next list element

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings like so:

```
ls = ['3395', 'test', '"city ', 'state"']
```

and I need to search it to find fields that have quotation marks so I can merge the fields together. Basically, the list I would like to have is:

```
ls_i_want = ['3395', 'test', '"city, state"']
```

I have the following code that basically accomplishes that:

```
ls[2:4] = [''.join(ls[2:4])]
```

and returns the list:

```
['3395', 'test', '"city state"']
```

This output is actually fine, but where I am struggling is the location of the of the quotes is variable; it won't always be at index 2 but the end quote will always be +2. I am trying to work down the path of this code:

```
for i, j in enumerate(ls):
    if '"' in j:
        ls[i:i+2] = ''.join(ls[i:i+2])
```

but that returns the list:

```
['3395', 'test', '"', 'c', 'i', 't', 'y',' ', 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'e', '"']
```

where am I going wrong? should I not be using enumerate?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a `csv` file?

Comment: You forgot to add the square brackets around `''.join(...)` in your 2nd snippet.

Comment: @Chillie yes, normally I wouldn't do it this way but due to the environment and existing architecture this is the way I have to fix it

Comment: @Aran-Fey, that worked! Submit it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I'd rather not. That's just a typo as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @DBA108642 this may be working for now, but I'd like to point out that modifying the object you're iterating over in a for loop is not a good idea. It would be a better practice to just count up your variable `i` in a while loop and break out when `i >= len(ls)`.

Comment: I think you'll also have to loop over a copy of your list, because after you merge 2 elements your indices will be off by 1.

Comment: It looks as though you've split the contents of a `csv` file. You can use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module which will automatically handle quoted strings containing commas.

Comment: @DBA108642 ugh, sorry to hear that. Does your solution work for multiple commas in a "cell"?

Comment: @Chillie it doesn't, but none of the cells have more than one comma

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split-python/43067525) in GyuHyeon Choi's answer. Basically I can just take the string before splitting it and feed it into a csv.reader and format it like so:

```
cStr = '3395,test,"city,state"'
newStr = [ '"{}"'.format(x) for x in list(csv.reader([cStr], delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[0] ]
```

to get the output I want, and it is variable so if there's more than 1 comma in a field it accounts for it.