# Split by comma and how to exclude comma from quotes in split in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am struggling to split this string on the basis of comma but comma inside the double quotes should be ignored.

```
cStr = 'aaaa,bbbb,"ccc,ddd"' 

expected result : ['aaaa','bbbb',"ccc,ddd" ]
```

please help me, I tried different methods as mentioned in below soln but couldn't resolve this issue [I am not allowed to use csv, pyparsing module]

there is already similar question asked before for the below input.

```
cStr = '"aaaa","bbbb","ccc,ddd"'
```

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split-python)

```
result = ['"aaa"','"bbb"','"ccc,ddd"']
```

Comment: there is a solution using ```pyparsing``` in the same link that you have given. have you tried that?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, basically I am not allowed to use most of the 3rd part library (pyparsing, csv) but I can use `re` tho

Comment: Duplicate of [Split by comma and how to exclude comma from quotes in split ... Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split-python)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way I handle this is to use a regex alternation which eagerly matches double quoted terms first, before non quoted CSV terms:

```py
import re

cStr = 'aaaa,bbbb,"ccc,ddd"'
matches = re.findall(r'(".*?"|[^,]+)', cStr)
print(matches)  # ['aaaa', 'bbbb', '"ccc,ddd"']
```

Comment: thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, it solved the issue but what would we do if we have double quote inside the string.

cStr = 'aaaa,"ccc,ddd","bb"bb"'

expected result -> ['aaaa', '"ccc,ddd"', '"bb"bb"']

Comment: To address both comments, if you expect unbalanced quotes then regex isn't the right tool and you should use a parser or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension, no other libraries needed:

```
cStr = 'aaaa,bbbb,"ccc,ddd"'

# split by ," afterwards by , if item does not end with double quotes
l = [
    item.split(',') if not item.endswith('"') else [item[:-1]]
    for item in cStr.split(',"')
]
print(sum(l, []))
```

Out:

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc,ddd']
```

Comment: The `ccc,ddd` in your output is missing its double quotes.  Probably just a small fix.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in three steps-

```
cstr = 'aaaa,bbbb,"ccc,ddd","eee,fff,ggg"'
```

**Step 1-**

```
X = cstr.split(',"')
```

**Step 2-**

```
regular_list = [i if '"' in i else i.split(",") for i in X ]
```

**Step 3-**

```
final_list = []
for i in regular_list:
    if type(i) == list:
        for j in i:
            final_list.append(j)
    else:
        final_list.append('"'+i)
```

**Final output -**

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', '"ccc,ddd"', '"eee,fff,ggg"']
```