# read csv without using import csv

Tags: python, csv

read csv without using  import csv in python

"name","sem","math","physics","chemistry"
"devendran","1,2,3","90","90","90"
"devendran","4","99","88","77"

expected output is

{'name': 'devendran', 'sem': '1,2,3', 'math': '90', 'physics': '90', 'chemistry': '90'}
{'name': 'devendran', 'sem': '4', 'math': '99', 'physics': '88', 'chemistry': '77'}

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing nor a custom tutorial service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only complication is you want to split on commas except within quotes without using CSV (and I assume other external modules)

- You can use pure Python function tokenize from [Split by comma and how to exclude comma from quotes in split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067373/split-by-comma-and-how-to-exclude-comma-from-quotes-in-split/71080500#71080500)

**Code**

```
def tokenize( string, separator = ',', quote = '"' ):
    """
    Split a comma separated string into a List of strings.

    Separator characters inside the quotes are ignored.

    :param string: A string to be split into chunks
    :param separator: A separator character
    :param quote: A character to define beginning and end of the quoted string
    :return: A list of strings, one element for every chunk
    """
    comma_separated_list = []

    chunk = ''
    in_quotes = False

    for character in string:
        if character == separator and not in_quotes:
            comma_separated_list.append(chunk)
            chunk = ''

        else:
            chunk += character
            if character == quote:
                in_quotes = False if in_quotes else True

    comma_separated_list.append( chunk )

    return comma_separated_list

# Read file 'test.txt'
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.rstrip()           # remove trailing '\n'
        line = tokenize(line)          # split on "," except for quotes
        if i == 0:
            header = line              # header row
        else:
            # Dictionary comprehension for header, value pairs
            result.append({h:l for h, l in zip(header, line)})

    print(*result, sep = "\n")
```

**Output**

```
{'"name"': '"devendran"', '"sem"': '"1,2,3"', '"math"': '"90"', '"physics"': '"90"', '"chemistry"': '"90"'}
{'"name"': '"devendran"', '"sem"': '"4"', '"math"': '"99"', '"physics"': '"88"', '"chemistry"': '"77"'}
```

**File: test.txt**

```
"name","sem","math","physics","chemistry" 
"devendran","1,2,3","90","90","90"
"devendran","4","99","88","77"
```